# Replaced old 3-4 year old thermal paste, temp goes up to 90 degrees celcius over time

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, overheating, intel-core-i5

So i slapped on some new thermal paste, reinstalled cpu cooler (ive got a intel i5 4570)
and noticed my idle temp was around 50, when entering games it slowly rises degree by degree over time before hitting 90+, i placed a around pea sized amount of thermal paste as always. could it be i didnt mount the cpu cooler back correctly or something?

edit: i will remount the cpu cooler, this time pushing it against the cpu more, and make sure the lil pins that intel stock coolers have are tight.

edit 2: i remember it being 10-15 degrees cooler with the old paste. i remember after reapplying paste and trying to mount the cooler i had some issues, and it was a bit wiggly, i probably didnt mount it right.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is probably an installation error and / or paste not properly covering the whole area to be covered and no more. May try doing it again.

Comment: CPUs can easily run at 90°C, especially under heavy loads. The only worry is if it used to be cooler *under the same load*, which you didn't mention.

Comment: My real question is, after the load ceases, how quickly does the temperature drop? if it is not very quickly (like less than a minute to get back to 50C on all cores), then either you don't have good contact between the heat sink and the cpu casing, or the heat sink is swamped (it cant evacuate heat to air fast enough to be able to continue drawing heat out of the CPU). if remounting everything doesn't work, consider replacing the fan, or perhaps the entire unit. I've never found stock coolers to be sufficient except on low TDP chips, so if you have one, consider an upgrade.

Comment: and the heat sink should mount very firmly to the CPU. you should not have any "wiggle" at all. if you didn;t spread the thermal paste, do so. relying on the compression to spread the paste is not always reliable (though that is a contraversial statement and some will disagree with me; theres just no way to know it was evenly spread unless you do it yourself).

Comment: Sounds like a simple solution, install the heatsink, properly so it has even pressure and doesn’t wiggle

Answer (score 1):

As per your edits, if the temperatures are 10-15° higher than before, and especially if the cooler is "wiggly", you have to reinstall the cooler properly.

A couple of thoughts:

- A pea sized amount of thermal paste could be too much - you're supposed to put as least as possible on your CPU to cover it completely, and for the cooler to "sit on the CPU" nicely. Too much thermal paste actually insulates your CPU and prevents heat to transfer to the cooler efficiently. The paste is only there to cover the small imperfections between the cpu and the cooler.
- The cooler should not move at all after you install it - it should be completely flat on the CPU and fixated on the motherboard with the pins.
- Make sure you buy a thermal paste that performs well and has good heat conductivity. A new paste with bad heat conductivity can actually perform worse than an old paste.